# How to create java.security.PublicKey from AsymmetricKeyParameter

Tags: bouncycastle, ecdsa

Hi I'm trying to write a public key to a PEM file.

`org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPEMWriter` seem to be the right tool, but it uses `org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaMiscPEMGenerator` which expects keys that is an instance of `java.security.PublicKey`.

Unfortunately, all the rest of the project I'm working on uses `AsymmetricKeyParameter` for public keys. I checked inside it has everything you would want to know from a public key, including point G and curve order, but it's not compatible with `java.security.PublicKey`.

Is there a way to use `JcaPEMWriter` if what I have is instances of `AsymmetricKeyParameter`? I use ECDSA key by the way.

(I am at first surprised at this because BouncyCastle's `JcaPEMWriter` isn't compatible with their own class, `AsymmetricKeyParameter`)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like the [`JcaPEMWriter`](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/openssl/jcajce/JcaPEMWriter.html) can directly handle an [`AsymmetricKeyParameter`](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/params/AsymmetricKeyParameter.html) object. But it is relatively easy to convert an [`AsymmetricKeyParameter`](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/params/AsymmetricKeyParameter.html) object to a [`PublicKey`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/security/PublicKey.html) object.

For this BouncyCastle's [`EC5Util`](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/jcajce/provider/asymmetric/util/EC5Util.html) class can be applied which handles the conversion from [`ECDomainParameters`](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/params/ECDomainParameters.html) to [`ECParameterSpec`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/security/spec/ECParameterSpec.html) and from BouncyCastle's [`ECPoint`](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/math/ec/ECPoint.html) to Java's [`ECPoint`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/security/spec/ECPoint.html).

The [`PublicKey`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/security/PublicKey.html) object can then be exported as before with the [`JcaPEMWriter`](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/openssl/jcajce/JcaPEMWriter.html) as an X.509/SPKI PEM encoded public key:

```
// AsymmetricKeyParameter object containing the public EC key
AsymmetricKeyParameter asymmetricKeyParameter = ...

// Convert AsymmetricKeyParameter object to PublicKey object
ECPublicKeyParameters ecPublicKeyParameters = (ECPublicKeyParameters)asymmetricKeyParameter;
ECParameterSpec ecParameterSpec = EC5Util.convertToSpec(ecPublicKeyParameters.getParameters());
ECPoint ecPoint = EC5Util.convertPoint(ecPublicKeyParameters.getQ());
ECPublicKeySpec ecPublicKeySpec = new ECPublicKeySpec(ecPoint, ecParameterSpec);
PublicKey publicKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC").generatePublic(ecPublicKeySpec);
        
// Export PublicKey object with JcaPEMWriter in X.509/SPKI format, PEM encoded
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by Topaco did not work for me (possibly because I am using `JSch`), as it throws exception (cannot cast `Ed25519PublicKeyParameters` to `ECPublicKeyParameters`).

After studying the [BC](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java) code for a bit I found a line of code in `KeyFactorySpi.java` that hint me to the proper way to create the pub key from existing data:

```java
AsymmetricKeyParameter keyParameter = OpenSSHPublicKeyUtil.parsePublicKey(blob.getData());
OpenSSHPublicKeySpec keySpec = new OpenSSHPublicKeySpec(OpenSSHPublicKeyUtil.encodePublicKey(keyParameter));
PublicKey publicKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("EdDSA").generatePublic(keySpec);
```

This returns a `BCEdDSAPublicKey` instance, as expected.